# Error while building old Android Kernel 3.10

Tags: android, linux, build, linux-kernel, asus

I'm trying to build an old Android Kernel which is provided by Asus.
I've uploaded the source code here : https://github.com/dchenaux/android_kernel_asus_z300c

I'm getting the following error :

```
arch/x86/kernel/setup.c: In function ‘setup_arch’:
arch/x86/kernel/setup.c:1134:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘early_init_dt_scan’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  early_init_dt_scan(x86_fdt_header());
  ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
```

Does someone know where it could come from ? Is it my environment ? Or the configuration ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: try disabling the warnings and try again, to disable the warnings remove ```-Werror``` from ```CFLAGS```, ```CPPFLAGS``` etc.; which you can find in Makefile's or build scripts.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick !